# How to extract numbers from Excel cell and then sum across rows?

Tags: excel

I am using Excel for resource planning and am trying to extract the % allocation for each person (sometimes multiple in a single cell) across several rows of projects.

I have been able to extract the percentage for a specific person in a single cell but am unsure how to then sum if and only if that person exists in other cells.

Here is what I am using for a single cell:

```
=MID(M204,SEARCH(B208,M204)+LEN(B208)+2,3)
```

This searches for a specific name within a cell, then looks for the percentage after (by finding the character location + number of characters in the name) and returns the next 3 characters (which is the % allocation). Ideally, I would like this to be flexible so it could return 5 or 50 or 100 rather than a fixed width but have not reached that point yet.

See this screenshot for what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Hm, having two names possible in a cell will make a formula a little trickier.  Would a VBA solution be okay?

Comment: I considered eliminating the ability of having two (or more!) names in a cell but we need that flexibility. VBA is not ideal but yes that could work, especially if it allows dynamic return of the % (5  v 10 v 100) rather than fixed char count and also sums across rows correctly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you have the flexibility to format the data in a different way?

Comment: If VBA isn't ideal, a quick option for you is to just put all that info in another area, using `Text to Columns`, and a Space as a delimiter...then move some data around. I can suggest a solution like that, but it requires a bit of manual manipulation...or a VBA solution would be a little quicker, but I understand if macros aren't feasable for you, just let me know.

Comment: I think the VBA solution could work if it means less manual manipulation. I want the doc to essentially be able to update live (or through macro) when changes are made rather than having to shift the data around each time a change is made. Also, would the VBA solution work if rows are added/removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a solution possible with VBA. Insert this function into a workbook module, and use it like this:

`=sumPercentage([week number],[name to look up],[range of percentages])`

(It should work if rows are removed too.)

```
Function sumPercentage(wk As String, employee As String, rng As Range) As Double
Dim cel As Range
Dim multNames() As String
Dim i       As Long

For Each cel In rng
    If InStr(1, cel, ",") > 0 And InStr(1, cel, "%") Then
        ' There are more than one person in the cell
        multNames = Split(cel.Value, ",")
        For i = LBound(multNames) To UBound(multNames)
            Debug.Print multNames(i)
            If Trim(Left(Trim(multNames(i)), WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", Trim(multNames(i))))) = employee Then
                sumPercentage = sumPercentage + Mid(multNames(i), WorksheetFunction.Search("(", multNames(i)) + 1, WorksheetFunction.Search("%", multNames(i)) - WorksheetFunction.Search("(", multNames(i)) - 1)
            End If
        Next i
    ElseIf cel.Value <> "" And InStr(1, cel, "%") Then
        If Trim(Left(cel.Value, WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", cel.Value))) = employee Then
            sumPercentage = sumPercentage + Mid(cel.Value, WorksheetFunction.Search("(", cel.Value) + 1, WorksheetFunction.Search("%", cel.Value) - WorksheetFunction.Search("(", cel.Value) - 1)
        End If
    End If
Next cel
sumPercentage = sumPercentage / 100
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much. This will be a huge time saver for me and my team.

Comment: FYI, the function is actually =sumPercentage([week number],[name to look up],[range of percentages]) but I figured that out. Is there a reason that the Week Number is needed if the percentage range is also selected?

Comment: @A.Ali - D'oh! I'll edit the format for the formula - To your second question, I wasn't sure if the `Week #` was *always* directly above the first row of data, so I let you choose it separately. If they're always like this, I can edit the Function to only need a name to find, and a range. It'll then use the first row in that range as the Week.  Would that work?

Comment: I think this should work as is, with the Week Number as an explicit argument in the function. I just did not understand why it was needed at all, as long as the range is given. I am having some issues now when I pull this over to my full workbook: If I choose a range of just a few rows (<22) I get the right value but when I extend to more (I currently have 200), I get #VALUE! error. Any ideas why? Some rows may have blanks which seems fine and I confirmed that all cells have the same category type.

Comment: It seems like the error is caused when a cell has a name without a percentage. (e.g. [John, Bob] vs [John (10%), Bob (25%)]) Is there a way around that? Perhaps a cell could be ignored if there is no percentage? Sometimes we will use TBD or other info in a cell and it would be better to just have it ignored rather than break the formula entirely.

Comment: @A.Ali - Ahh, okay. See the edit. I just added an additional condition, If the Cell has % in there, continue, otherwise move along.  Let me know if there are any other issues!

Comment: Thank you! I get some errors if a cell has a percentage for one name but not for another (e.g. [John, Bob (20%)]) however that's not a use case that I expect to happen. Just wanted to call out the edge case for reference. Thanks so much for your help. This will be extremely valuable for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can flatten your data, then a pivot table is what you want.

Make your data look like this:

[image]

And then add a pivot table with Week in Columns, Name in Rows, and Sum of Capacity in Values:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however this would require flattening and updating the pivot table with each change, correct? We use the existing format to visualize who is assigned to a project (and at what capacity) week over week so we would not want to lose that view. The manual process would be too time-consuming to work through with each change.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `Text to Columns`, and using SPACE as a delimiter.

You'll put the info in a new area in your spreadsheet, and for those cells with multiple people, just cut/paste below the others.  Then find/replace `,` with nothing.

Then, it's a simple `SUMIF()`: `=SUMIF([name range],Name,[percent range])`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I get how I can do that manually. Any thoughts on a way to automate this? What if I change Charlotte's allocation to 100% in Week 3? I don't want to go through the manual Text to Columns and Sum approach each time.

Comment: @A.Ali - If you want to automate this, you'll need VBA...in which case I would suggest a different way to do it. I'll post another answer.

Comment: Open to other approaches that yield the same result if my current thinking is wrong. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Well you *can* do it with a formula but it is messy

```
=SUM(--IFERROR(LEFT(MID(MID($A$2:$A11,SEARCH($B2,$A$2:$A$11),999),SEARCH("(",MID($A$2:$A$11,SEARCH($B2,$A$2:$A$11),999))+1,999),
SEARCH("%",MID(MID($A$2:$A$11,SEARCH($B2,$A$2:$A$11),999),SEARCH("(",MID($A$2:$A$11,SEARCH($B2,$A$2:$A$11),999))+1,999))),0))
```

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]